# In multi thread process, when "[Switching to Thread]" in gdb?

Tags: debugging, gdb, reverse-engineering, exploit

When I'm debugging multi thread process in gdb, I meet "[Switching to Thread ~~ (LWP ~~)]". When the thread is changing to other thread, and why? I guess switching can be occurred by interrupt such as breakpoints. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is gdb notifying you that gdb's notion of the selected thread has changed.  This happens if there is some debugging event, like a signal or a breakpoint stop, in a thread other than the one you had last selected.